# C++ Qt - Hierarchy in the elements added to a GUI

Tags: qt

In general, is the order in which I add my widgets into each other, the same order I access them back?

Example:

If I have a bunch of `QPushButton` in a `QHBoxLayout`, and this layout in a `Window::ui`,
can I access those button by simply `ui->button_name`? or Do I must do `ui->layout->itemAt(idx)`?

EDIT: My question aims to find an easy way to access elements that are deep into the hierarchy, like a label in a frame, inside a layout, inside a frame, inside the window etc...

PS: Also, I would really appreciate any documentations about good practices of GUI architecture!

Comment: Create a member of your class that points to the required widget.  Set that pointer when you create the widget.

Comment: Yes, that's what I always do. it just took me a while to figure out that I could access things through ui->name_object instead of itemAt(idx), which returns a not necessarily very handy QLayoutItem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ui->object_name` you don;t need to worry about the layout!
It's possible to redesign the layout, eg. for different platforms, without changing any of the C++ code.

There are a couple of good books on Qt and the sample code is very good.

[C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354160)

[Advanced Qt Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321635906)